# Merging more than 1 image with a base image

Tags: php, imagecreatefrompng

I use this code to merge two images. Can someone please help me to merge 2 source images with 1 base image. For eg. I have these images base.jpg, image1.jpg, image2.jpg. I want to merge image1.jpg and image2.jpg on base.jpg. I'm using this code to merge two images.

```
$dest = imagecreatefromjpeg('base.jpg');
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg('$image1.jpg');

imagealphablending($dest, false);
imagesavealpha($dest, true);

imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 229, 285, 0, 0, 70, 70, 100); 
Imagejpeg($dest, '$new.jpg', 100);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
```

Comment: So... what's you getting from your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically we will be putting many different images all together on one big ‘canvas’ image. If you need to do that for some reason, read on to find out how.

[Combining multiple images using PHP](http://diceattack.wordpress.com/2011/01/03/combining-multiple-images-using-php-and-gd/)